# Run cmd/terminal command on run in visual studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, webpack, build

## Background

I'm creating a small project in Visual Studio to learn React. However when I change something in my app.tsx, I have to run the

```js
node_modules\.bin\webpack app.tsx --config webpack-config.js
```

command for my project to re-run the webpack so i can build and run my changed code.

There must be a better way to do this right?

### What I want to do

I want to know if there is a way to automatically run this command when I press the run button in Visual Studio. Or if there is a better way of doing this, know how to simplify this process.

When I've done other javascript projects I've used vagrant or a build server that has been automated for this purpose (check code for changes, update the "converted/build/compile" code). But those processes have been automated from the start and not by me so I don't really know what to do.

### What I've tried

Since I've never encountered a situation where this was an issue, I don't really know how to address this problem. I have searched for ways to "auto-run commands in the cmd/terminal on run" and similar search strings, but they all lead to solutions to problems other than this.

### Question

How can I configure VS/implement a code snippet that runs the

```js
node_modules\.bin\webpack app.tsx --config webpack-config.js
```

command in the cmd/terminal when I press Run in Visual Studio?

## EDIT:

I have solved the problem.

It says on their official [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) that the feature I need is **"watch"** and it says that this feature is:

```js
In webpack-dev-server and webpack-dev-middleware watch mode is enabled by default.
```

But it is not. So in order to enable it I had to add a line to the webpack-config.js with **watch:true**

The now working config looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
devtool: 'source-map',
entry: "./app.tsx",
mode: "development",
output: {
    filename: "./app-bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.tsx$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        }
    ]
},
watch:true
}
```

Now I only have to run the command once and it checks for changes in my project code and re-packs the webpack automatically.